# Using Perl, how can I remove the contents of a specific tag in an HTML document?

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I'm new to Perl. I have to find and replace in multiple line.

```
$content =~ s/<picture[^>]*>(.*?)<\/picture>//gis;
```

I tried these code. All the tags are replaced in my file. What is my mistake any one help me?

My tag is,

```
<picture width='960' height='705' baseline='360'>
    <pict-header>
    </pict-header>
</picture>
```

now replaced by

```
<picture></picture>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to remove any tags inside a `<picture>` tag, and any attributes on that tag?

Comment: yeah, I have remove all attributes and inside of all tags in '<picture>'.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what I think you want to do, here is what you need to change. Your expression matches any `<picture>` tag up to the first `</picture>` tag, no matter whether it actually closes the first tag you match or not.

Assuming that it's illegal to nest `<picture>` tags, all you need to do is add `<picture></picture>` in the replacement section of the substitution, e.g.:

```
$content =~ s/<picture[^>]*>(.*?)<\/picture>/<picture><\/picture>/gis;
```

TIP: When dealing with expressions that have slashes in them, do something like this so you don't need to escape your slashes:

```
$content =~ s@<picture[^>]*>(.*?)</picture>@<picture></picture>@gis;
```

This is still not perfect! For example, this:

```
<picture stuff="adfgerth"><picture stuff="235wefw45"><somejunk /></picture></picture>
```

will be replaced with:

`<picture></picture></picture>`

but now you've gotten to the point where a regular expression is not enough, and you probably want an XML parser.

Comment: "$content =~ s/<picture[^>]*>(.*?)<\/picture>/<picture><\/picture>/gis;" Doesn't replace in my file these code.

Comment: Are you loading your input line by line or loading the entire content into a single buffer? You need to do the latter to do a multiline search. The usual `while (<>) { stuff }` won't work.

Comment: `open(FOUT,">$filename") || die("Cannot Open File");
foreach my $line (@fcont) {
    $line =~ s/<picture[^>]*>(.*?)<\/picture>/<picture><\/picture>/gis;
    print FOUT $line;
}
close FOUT;` These my code.

Comment: I think `$line` gives it away. ;-)

Comment: These my code.

`open(FILE, "$filename") or die("Cannot open the html files for reading\n");
    my(@fcont) = <FILE>;
    close FILE;
    open(FOUT,">$filename") || die("Cannot Open File");
    foreach my $line (@fcont)
    {
       $line =~ s/<picture[^>]*>(.*?)<\/picture>/<picture><\/picture>/gis;
       print FOUT $line;
    }
    close FOUT;` Doesn't replace my file. Any one help me.

Comment: Scrap the for loop and replace it with `my $line = join("", @fcount); $line =~ ...pattern...`

Answer (score 2):

You can save a lot of headache by using an HTML parser to parse HTML:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

die "Need filename\n" unless @ARGV == 1;
my ($filename) = @ARGV;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(file => $filename);

while (my $token = $parser->get_token) {
    if ($token->is_start_tag('picture')) {
        $parser->get_tag('/picture');
        print "<picture></picture>";
    }
    else {
        print $token->as_is;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sinan's answer works, but an even better solution might be to use a DOM parser, such as [`Mojo::DOM`](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) (which is part of the [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) framework). Then you can do some very simple manipulations like

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $content = <<'END';
<picture width='960' height='705' baseline='360'>
    <pict-header>
    </pict-header>
</picture>
END

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($content);

$dom->at('picture')->replace('<picture></picture>')->root;

print $dom;
```